# How to properly lay out columns in an HTML Bootstrap Treeview inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm using the [Bootstrap Treeview library](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) to display some hierarchical data on a page. I'm trying to have each node of the tree broken down into a few columns but I can't seem to get the elements to do it properly.

If I try using `span` elements in the `text` property of the tree like this:

```
<span style="background-color: yellow; width: 50%;">foo</span><span style="background-color: red; width: 50%">foo</span>
```

I get this output:

[image: span tag results]

If I try using `div` elements in the `text` property of the tree like this:

```
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 50%;">foo</div><div style="background-color: red; width: 50%">foo</div>
```

I get output like this:

[image: div tag results]

I've tried various combinations all with similar mixed results. What can I do to make the columns all show up on a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div is a block element whereas span is not. Try inline-block styling on the div and give it some width.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Hey nice. Spent so much time on this and your answer just about does it (just changed to percentage instead of pixels and added a parent div). Thanks!